# VTK coloring tube filter with connectivity information

Tags: python, data-visualization, vtk

I have a molecule I want to represent with spheres and tubes connecting them. I'd like to color the tubes according to connectivity information. Meaning that I have various disconnected regions or disconnected components I would like to color differently per region. So far I have this, in python and it works. I have commented what I tried to do to achieve this. The avariable `data` is a PolyData array that contains points, scalars and cells with the connectivity information.

```
tube = vtk.vtkTubeFilter()
tube.SetInput(data)
tube.SetNumberOfSides(5);
#tube.SetVaryRadiusToVaryRadiusByAbsoluteScalar()
tube.SetVaryRadiusToVaryRadiusOff()
tube.SetRadius(0.1)

"""appendFilter = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
appendFilter.AddInputConnection(tube.GetOutputPort())
appendFilter.Update()

connectivityFilter = vtk.vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter()
connectivityFilter.SetInputConnection(appendFilter.GetOutput())
connectivityFilter.ScalarConnectivityOn()
connectivityFilter.FullScalarConnectivityOn()
connectivityFilter.SetExtractionModeToAllRegions()
connectivityFilter.ColorRegionsOn()
connectivityFilter.Update()
"""
#print (connectivityFilter.GetNumberOfExtractedRegions())

tubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
tubeMapper.SetInputConnection(tube.GetOutputPort())
tubeMapper.Update()
```

And this is how it looks so far
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually have something working but I am not sure if there is a problem with the connectivity definition. I was only forgetting the word "port" in `getOutputPort`. Anyways, here is the answer (I am omitting atom and tube radius and other irrelevant options)

```
tube = vtk.vtkTubeFilter()
tube.SetInput(data)
tube.SetVaryRadiusToVaryRadiusOff()
tube.SetRadius(tuberad)

appendFilter = vtk.vtkAppendPolyData()
appendFilter.AddInputConnection(tube.GetOutputPort())
appendFilter.Update()

connectivityFilter = vtk.vtkPolyDataConnectivityFilter()
connectivityFilter.SetInputConnection(appendFilter.GetOutputPort())
connectivityFilter.SetExtractionModeToAllRegions()
connectivityFilter.ColorRegionsOn()
connectivityFilter.Update()

tubeMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
tubeMapper.SetInputConnection(connectivityFilter.GetOutputPort())
tubeMapper.SetScalarRange(connectivityFilter.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray("RegionId").GetRange())
tubeMapper.Update()
```

It ends up looking good, but you may notice that some apparently connected components are still colored differently and I still wonder why.

[image]